# Play Flash(.swf) files in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, media-streaming, video-richmedia

Are there any options/webparts to play flash(.swf) files in SharePoint Online modern and classic pages?

Comment: Are you trying to play these files on modern pages or classic pages? If classic then do you have access to content editor webpart?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions given [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b766647d-0b1e-464b-a557-3295093aceb8/how-to-play-swf-file-in-sharepoint-online-or-office-365)?

Comment: @GaneshSanap All the suggestions in those article is 3rd party solutions.I'm looking for OOB options.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Have to play the video in both modern and classic pages. Yes, have access to CEWP.

Comment: I am sure you know, Adobe will end support of Flash Player on December 31, 2020 and MS will remove it phase by phase from their browsers https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/adobe-flash-end-of-support, not sure what Chrome or Firefox will do, but we have already started thinking about stopping flash usage completely, it's not easy but ... Is there any option to convert those SWF files to MP4 or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing SWF files in SharePoint Online is no longer supported since Flash is in the retiring process in all browsers.

There are no long OOB solutions provided by Microsoft 365 for this requirement, either in modern or classic experience of SharePoint Online.

I would suggest you use other types of video files as an alternative.

References:

[Types of files that cannot be added to a list or library.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3)

[Microsoft Stream formats and codecs.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/input-audio-video-formats-codecs)